# why would session_commit() cause 'Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted '

Tags: php, session, memory, out-of-memory, php-7.1

I am calling `session_commit()` before I call `header('Location: ... ')` and then immediately `exit`.
What would cause in `session_commit` to get **FATAL ERROR: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 140708235403264 bytes)**
This is on my production servers, so I need to be careful before I go in and put a bunch of echos/debugs.

I am using php 7.1.9  Session handler is the default `files` handler.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more context?  How much data is being stored in the session variable?

Comment: How much data can I store in session before I commit it? I will have to check on that.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to increase your memory limit to 140 TB. `answered Jul 2 '28`

Comment: The error was opcach/just memory leaking related it seems, restarting the server made it go away.

Comment: @ficuscr usually when u get this type of errors, increasing the memory won't help. It will simply write more into it until it overflow the new boundary.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka Glad you got it sorted. That was sarcasm. I got a good laugh out of the error message. 140,708 GB is a lot of memory and pretty suggestive something is awry.